# What would cause brakes to get this hot?

Tags: honda, brakes, crv

I have a 2010 Honda crv. Had the brakes done about 6 months ago by a reputable mechanic. Yesterday while driving home there was some vibration in the front and by the time I got home (20 minutes) I could smell the brakes. They were REALLY hot, to the point I threw some snow on the rotor and it instantly vaporized.  This was true of both the driver and passenger side. I've never had anything like that happen before. What would the likely cause be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you have a sticking brake caliper. As a note, throwing snow onto a hot brake rotor is a *very bad idea* if you want the rotor to not be warped. Uneven cooling of the rotor could spell its death. Sudden uneven cooling is even worse for it.

Comment: +1 to what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said. Sounds like a sticking caliper situation - with one *minor* addition. Since you say both sides were overheated, you could also have an issue with the master cylinder or another component that is affecting the whole front-end of your braking system. *And as an added note in the sudden temp shock, it’s important to remember that superheated things (metals included) can violently warp, shatter or even **explode** from too much shock! So it is very important to avoid tests like that in the future.*

Comment: I would go with Kyle and the sticking master cylinder or a faulty abs unit - calliper possibly but two at the same time... just sounds too much like coincidence but you never know and if they are the cause and cheaper I'm happy to be wrong.. :)